# Is this in any way useful if (this != null)?

Tags: java

I came across some tests that included code like this:

```
if (this != null) {
    do something
}
```

Is this if clause of any use? 
Is there a purpose I don't get that makes this useful?

Comment: Wait, what? Sorry but this can hardly be called a question

Comment: It would be better if you can provide the reference where you have seen this code.

Comment: I saw it in tests, i  did not know a right answer.

Comment: In that case, it can be used in tests.

Comment: @Pete ofcourse it can be used, but why would you ever want to write something like that; the `this` reference (which refers to the current object) can't ever be `null` in Java.

Comment: FWIW, this may be a fragment the asker saw, written by someone coming from a C++ background.  Unlike Java, in C++, it's possible for a (non-virtual) member function to be called with a null `this` pointer, and checks on `this` can make sense for debugging.

Comment: How is this "not a real question"? The writer sees a line of code whose purpose he does not understand, he admits he's a beginner, and he'd like someone to explain to him what this code accomplishes, or if the original author must have simply been confused. There are two very clear and to the point answers.

Comment: @Jesper Then you would have passed the test. Some code constructs only ever appear in tests to see if people say WTF to them.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`this` can never be `null` in Java so this kind of code is never useful.

Comment: Heh, because of the general badness of the question I hadn't even noticed he was using <code>this</code>.

Comment: Well, in theory it would be null in a static context, but the compiler will prevent you from ever doing that :-)

Comment: @kasperjj `this` doesn't exist in a static context (i.e. it simply isn't there) - it's a bit strange to say that something that doesn't exist would "in theory be `null`"...

Answer (score 2):

In Java the `this` keyword can only be used in a non-static method of a class.

Thus, if you are ever running code in the method, `this` cannot ever be `null` because you are guaranteed to have an instance of that object, otherwise the method would have never been able to be called.

Comment: Disappointment: With if (this == null) { a(); }, the compiler does not recognize a() as dead code.

Answer (score 1):

The programmer was looking for a fancier way to write:

```
if (true) {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use "this" in a static environment that is the only place where "this" could be null.

You can call a static method or variable without an object, without an instance. "this" points to the current instance of the class. You can only use "this" if you have an object, so it will never be null.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a pretty clueless programmer, so don't believe a word I say (and correct me if I'm wrong!), but it calls to mind *cogito ergo sum* -- I think, therefore I am. Descartes [called it](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cogito_ergo_sum) "the first and the most certain which presents itself to whoever conducts his thoughts in order." Similarly, that `this != null` seems to be (in Java, anyway, from the sound of it) among the most trivial conclusions code can reach. Neat!

Comment: ha, do you open all your answers with this line? Edit: apparently you do :)

Comment: this isn't really an answer, is it?

Comment: No it's not. :-/ Should've been a comment, if it's worth saying at all.